# How to show an 'Undefined in Unicode' character

Tags: html, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to find a solution to be able to show 'Undefined Unicode' characters inputted by users.

As an example, when a user inputs `\u{1F979}` they should see a Face Holding Back Tears, instead they see a rectangle.
`\u{1F979}` belongs to the [Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/block/Sup_Symbols_And_Pictographs.html) which goes from 0x1F900 to 0x1F9FF

It's listed as undefined here: https://unicode-table.com/en/1F979/ and the same issue occurs here: https://unicodeplus.com/U+1F979

Should chars in the 'Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs' block be correctly rendered as emojis?
And if so what am I doing wrong. My regex does find the Unicode but the browser is not rendering it - `/(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff]|[\u1F900-\u1F9FF])/gi;`

Comment: U+1F979 was added in Unicode 14.0 which is currently the latest one.

Comment: Unicode 14.0 was released in 2021. Font and website support can lag

Comment: Rather than looking at secondary sites that may have incorrect or old information, you should refer to the unicode.org site, which is authoritative for all things Unicode. The code charts will text you exactly what characters are defined in any given version of Unicode. https://www.unicode.org/charts/